# Groebner basis of a toric ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, groebner-bases

I know about toric ideals that it is a sort of binomial ideal i.e. generated by $x^u - x^v$, where $Au = Av $ ( A is the associated matrix). So by finding all integer solutions of $AX = 0$, can we somehow find the generators of the toric ideal? More specifically, can we determine the grobner basis? With the help of the integer solutions?

Comment: I think the term you’ll want to lookup is Markov basis. I think the Markov basis will always be a Gröbner basis, but I’m not sure.

Comment: Can you provide/suggest any meterial for this topic?

Comment: I believe "Markov basis" refers to any generating set for the toric ideal -- so typically not a Groebner basis. You also don't generate the ideal from only considering $u-v$ in some lattice basis for the kernel of $A$ --- you need to saturate out various coordinate hyperplanes. There is pretty good software for computing these sorts of things -- normaliz and 4ti2 come to mind.